# Git - How to undo an accidental merge and create a branch instead

Tags: git, version-control

I'm ultra newbie on Git, I did mess like this:

[image: Git history - merge]

How can I now fix this mess which I marked? I just wanted to make a new branch and add a file there but I merged something.

Answer (score 1):

The command you must have done was `git merge [branchname]`.

The commands you needed to do was `git checkout -b [new_branchname] && git add [files...] && git commit`.

To undo the merge, use `git reset HEAD^` (just once) - you might need to use `--hard`.

If that's not what you meant, clarify your question.

Comment: Does 'git reset HEAD^' will delete my merged stuff?

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD^` will delete any changes you've made since the merge commit. `git reset HEAD^` will simply move the ref of the HEAD to `447e541`, and the changes of `56f8601` will show up as unstaged changes. In both of these cases, `447e541` and `56f8601` will remain intact, but `fe17e70` will be gone (but still recoverable with `git fsck`)

Comment: I made that change but now I don't know how to update my remote repo. git push don't work, git pull does something but on my bitbucket everything is still unchanged.

Comment: What does git push do? You can wipe out your remote git history with `--force`, but that's discouraged since it could affect other people who have pulled changes. I didn't know that you were pushing to a remote server. Please add more detail to your question (that's why you got downvoted, not enough detail.)